# conditional formatting entire row if all cells in that row are empty

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, textjoin

I'm trying figure out how to apply style to all rows, but only when entire row is empty, basically if any cell is not empty, the entire row should be skipped.
tried `=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(A1:Z)))` it doesn't work

Any tips?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 It's a blank sheet, nothing to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(, 1, $A1:$Z1)=""
```

[image]

skipping one (D) column:

```
=TEXTJOIN(, 1, $A1:$C1, $E1:$Z1)=""
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works very well. What if I'd like to ignore a column from checking? To ignore `C` column Use `=AND(TEXTJOIN(, 1, $A1:$B1)="", TEXTJOIN(, 1, $D1:$Z1,)="")` ?

Comment: @vanowm answer updated